# How do I loop over a list of numbers, add the one row's number to the previous rows, and append the result to a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have the following data loaded into a dataframe in Python:

```
id  index_num  quantity
001   0        10     
002   1        10   
003   2        10   
004   3        10   
005   4        10
```

For each ID number, I'm trying to total the quantities that come before each ID and then append the result to a new column so the dataframe will look like this:

```
id  index_num  quantity  sum
001   0        10         10  
002   1        10         20
003   2        10         30
004   3        10         40
005   4        10         50
```

I have tried writing a loop:

```
result = []
for value in df['index_num']:
    if value < 4:
        result.append(df.loc[df['index_num'] < 4, 'quantity'].sum())
    else:
        result.append('')
df["result"] = result   
print(df)
```

The output of that code totals the entire quantity column, rather than by each row. It also requires me to put a number as the condition, but I'd rather it automatically know to take the row number below it.
How can I make it so that the loop adds the previous rows and current row together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cumulative sum

```
df['sum'] = df['quantity'].cumsum()
```

```
    id  index_num   quantity    sum
0   1     0          10          10
1   2     1          10          20
2   3     2          10          30
3   4     3          10          40
4   5     4          10          50
```